# Trouble pulling records from a certain date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, between, date-range

I'm trying to pull data from a table that deals with visits to a certain location. Visitors arrive and upon check-in, a Visit Date is created. I need to pull a list of all the visits that took place between July 1, 2015 and December 31, 2015. Seems simple enough, right?

Here's my query:

```
SELECT VisitorID, VisitorName, VisitDate
FROM VisitList
WHERE VisitDate BETWEEN '07/01/2015' AND '12/31/2015'
```

(Note: I'm treating those dates as strings because the VisitDate field in this table has a varchar data type for some ridiculous reason -- I don't know who set it up that way but I've had to deal with this on several different occasions.)

The issue is that I'm getting all the right results, but I'm getting results for July-December of *2014* as well, and I only want 2015. What could be causing that, and how can I fix it?

I also tried casting the VisitDate field as a DATE data type and got rid of the quotes around the dates in the WHERE clause, but to no avail.

**UPDATE:**
Here's the query with the Cast:

```
SELECT VisitorID, VisitorName, CAST(VisitDate AS Date) as Visit_Date
FROM VisitList
WHERE VisitDate BETWEEN 07/01/2015 AND 12/31/2015
```

Comment: please provide the query with CAST. or maybe all kind of queries you have tried

Comment: Just updated it...

Comment: you need to use CAST in where clause not the SELECT :)

Comment: Gotcha. One of the other answers just suggested that and it did the trick. Thanks :)

Comment: After some time when your database will have millions of row , multiple join, you are gonna put another question here that my query is slow/very slow. because no index will help you here. so please change the datatype visitdate to DATE or any other form of date datatype. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT VisitorID, VisitorName, VisitDate FROM VisitList WHERE CAST(VisitDate As date) between CAST('07/01/2015' as date) and CAST('12/31/2015' as date)
```

You need to cast    varchar

values to type date before comparison.

Answer (score 0):

User **[STR_TO_DATE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/)**:

```
SELECT VisitorID, VisitorName, VisitDate
FROM VisitList
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(VisitDate , '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN str_to_date('07/01/2015', '%m/%d/%Y') AND str_to_date('12/31/2015', '%m/%d/%Y')
```